# Pubnub Chat System in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pubnub

we are building a chatting System using Pubnub SDK and there is a bug in receiving messages,
the problem is we are receiving the message twice

https://www.pubnub.com/docs/unity3d-c-sharp/pubnub-c-sharp-sdk#add-event-listeners

I am subscribing to events and unsubscribing following official documentation
and tried many times to debug and fix the issue but still it appears in some cases

help will be appreciated

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because bugs should be taken up with the code writer

Comment: what if the problem in the SDK  itself ? @BugFinder

Comment: Take to the people who write the sdk.

Comment: we did already, we put it here bcz we can reach large number of good devs who can help  faster if they faced the same issue before @BugFinder

Comment: Did you submit your code, SDK logs (enable SDK logging) and sub-key to ]PubNub Support(https://support.pubnub.com)? If not, please do so and we will figure this out for you. But I can assure you it is not SDK bug as we have many customers in production and duplicate messages are (or at least, have been) always client implementation bug. Once we have code and SDK logs, we can typically find the issue quickly.

Comment: We switched to Mono build in android and the issue didn’t occur,

But we need to build in IL2CPP.


We found this comment in the PNUnityWebRequest
//Got an exception when using JSON serialisation for [],
//IL2CPP needs to know about the array type at compile time.
//So please define private static filed like this:

Is IL2CPP not supported, if so please advice  ?

Comment: I posted this internally to the PN SDK Engineers. You can always post to [PN Support](https://support.pubnub.com) directly, too. We have great free support.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do not call the listener multiple time in various places. So define the listener statically better.

Comment: it is a static one, it is related to the SDK limitation, they told that it will work in Mono not in IL2CPP so it is an SDK limitation.